# How to Select the Previous Active Cell in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm working on a VBA application that will look at the comment that was entered and tell someone if the comment they left was over 150 characters long. I have it working except that I need it the read the previous cell that was selected instead of the new cell I click on. An example would be if I put a comment on A3 and then click on G7, it would say tell me that there is no comment on G7 when I need it to say if the comment on A3 was over the character limit.

Comment: Use a global variable to capture the clicked-on cell: when the selection_change event runs you can check that range instead of the just-selected one.  If you include your current code (always a good idea here) someone might suggest the edits you need.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time I post on here. I'm new to Stack Overflow and wasn't sure how about posting code on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution I was able to figure out.

```
Dim cmt As Comment
Dim currTarget As Range
If prevTarget Is Nothing Then
  Set currTarget = Target
  Set prevTarget = currTarget
Else
  Set prevTarget = currTarget
  Set currTarget = Target
End If
Set cmt = prevTarget.Comment
```

I then call 'cmt' if the comment is over 150 characters with an if statement